# Why does the movement of my canvas box increase on click?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

The Js Fiddle attached draw a box where ever the mouse is clicked. It works as expected for the most part. Except every time a new box is drawn on the canvas it speeds up more and more every time to the point where it's way too fast.

I've `console.log`ed the `dx/dy` values and they are not increasing in value so it's not that, I don't think.

The dx value is what the position of the box is moving by.

Can any one shed some light?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var logger = document.getElementById('logger');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var dx = -2;
    var dy = -2;
    var boxColour = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    var boxSize = 20;
    var mousex,
        mousey;
    
    canvas.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      mousex = e.clientX;
      mousey = e.clientY;
      x = mousex - canvas.offsetLeft-(boxSize/2);
      y = mousey - canvas.offsetTop-(boxSize/2);
      draw();
    });
    
    function draw(){
      logger.innerHTML = "x: " + x + "y: " + y;
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      collistionDetection();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x,y,boxSize,boxSize);
      ctx.fillStyle=boxColour;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
      x+=dx;
      y+=dy;
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    };
    
    function collistionDetection(){
      if(x<0 || x>canvas.width-boxSize){
        dx = -dx;
        boxColour = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      };
      if(y<canvas.offsetTop-(boxSize/2) || y>canvas.height-boxSize){
        boxColour = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        dy = -dy;
      };
    };
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    canvas { background: #eee; display: block;
      margin: 0 auto; margin-top:10px;
      }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width='480' height='320'></canvas>
<div id="logger"></div>
```

Your help is always much appreciated.
Thanks
moe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your requestAnimationFrames are not being cleared so your animation function is just being called more and more frequently every time you click. I made a small change to your code below which seems to help.

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var logger = document.getElementById('logger');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var dx = -2;
    var dy = -2;
    var boxColour = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    var boxSize = 20;
    var mousex,
        mousey;
    var lastAnimationFrame;
    canvas.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      mousex = e.clientX;
      mousey = e.clientY;
      x = mousex - canvas.offsetLeft-(boxSize/2);
      y = mousey - canvas.offsetTop-(boxSize/2);
      cancelAnimationFrame(lastAnimationFrame)
      draw();
    });
    
    function draw(){
      logger.innerHTML = "x: " + x + "y: " + y;
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      collistionDetection();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x,y,boxSize,boxSize);
      ctx.fillStyle=boxColour;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
      x+=dx;
      y+=dy;
      lastAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    };
    
    function collistionDetection(){
      if(x<0 || x>canvas.width-boxSize){
        dx = -dx;
        boxColour = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
      };
      if(y<canvas.offsetTop-(boxSize/2) || y>canvas.height-boxSize){
        boxColour = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        dy = -dy;
      };
    };
```

```css
    * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    canvas { background: #eee; display: block;
      margin: 0 auto; margin-top:10px;
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width='480' height='320'></canvas>
<div id="logger"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. Marked as correct answer for timeliness and simplicity. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because by each mouse click, you are calling `draw` once again, and this call, as apparent in your code, is recursive and keeps calling itself. So, by each click, you have a chain of calls to `draw`.

You can add a boolean to check whether `draw` has initially been called, and if so, prevent subsequent calls inside your `draw` function:

```
if(!initialized)
{
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    initialized = true;
}
```